# ASP.NET Core Web API living inside a ASP.NET 4 IIS Web Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am tasked to to build a Web API application. The app will be hosted inside an existing web site - a pre-ASP.NET 5 web application with a WCF web service.

I wonder - can I build the web-api application using ASP.NET Core 1 in a way that it can happily exists as a sub application inside the already existing site in IIS?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to host the ASP.NET Core web API on the same application pool of your existing web application?

Comment: Yes. I am wondering what would it take to do so in terms of server side assemblies that need to be installed, and managing the application. The Servers are Windows Server 2008R2 + IIS7.5+ Most applications are managed through a third party vendor IIS plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it is not possible what you want. Please refer to the following documentation about hosting ASP.NET Core on IIS: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html.

If you specifically look at the .NET CLR version in the application pool it should be "No Managed Code" while your current website is set to a .NET framework version I assume. This is because ASP.NET Core is now cross plaform and completely web server agnostic. It even needs a little 'trick' (the ASP.NET Core Module) to work on IIS. See: "The module creates the reverse-proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server."

But if you follow the link provided above I think you'll manage to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, I'm doing the opposite of this scenario but conceptually its the same thing. You need to create your subsite as a separate application in IIS with its own app pool. That app pool needs to be configured No Managed Code per the instructions on the Docs site https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html

The only other thing you need to watch out for is that the web.config in the subsite will inherit some settings from the root web.config, so you need to remove or clear things sometimes like handlers, modules, etc.